# WordPress htaccess ignoring my redirect exclusions

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have the following in my htaccess file for my WordPress site:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^libertychurchnyc\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.libertychurchnyc\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^libertychurchnyc\.com/community-groups/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^libertychurchnyc\.com/podcasts/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/libertychurch\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

The site redirects perfectly BUT my exclusions for community-groups and podcasts is completely ignored.

I know I'm missing something here, but after going through a ton of posts here, I finally had to break down and ask what I've done wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Update... it appears my first exclusion is now working, but not the second one. ANY help at all will be greatly appreciated!!